# "we have different rhythms" vs "we have different paces"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, expressions

I was talking to a friend (who has passed some of his years in Canada), and I said to him

> It's difficult to meet to discuss about a problem because we have different rhythms.

and he agreed by saying

> ...it is true that we have different paces.

Now, since my English level is still not good enough, or at least it isn't as good as I would like, especially in terms of the richness and rightness of my vocabulary and expressions I should use, I'm not sure if I can say what I said and, if I can, are both sentences equivalent? Is one more common than the other? Which one sounds more familiar to native English speakers? I know that this might be different from country to country, but you can simply mention your country, if you wish.

To be honest, I used the term `rhythm` because it's also used in my mother language (of course translated). I didn't even know about pace.

Comment: We do "talk *about* something" but we "discuss something" not "discuss *about* something".

Comment: Yes, both would be idiomatic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question.

**Rhythm** can refer to the **stopping and starting** or **speeding up and slowing down** or
**ebb and flow** of *something*.

For example, if you are awake during the day (which is usual) and your friend is awake during the night (sometimes referred to as "being a **night owl**") you both have different personal rhythms (not to be confused with [**circadian rhythm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_rhythm).

**Pace** is usually used to describe **constant speed** while travelling, either literally or metaphorically

> The runners ran at a 4-minute-mile **pace**
>   The **pace** of life inside big cities is hectic

You two may be missing each other because

> your **rhythm** is not at the same **pace** as your friend, or
>   your friend's **pace** does not have the same **rhythm** as yours

Obviously, **pace** and **rhythm** wouldn't match since they mean different things, but by using them you both may be suggesting that you view your daily lives in different ways.

Comment: Since OP is apparently from Switzerland and his friend is/was in Canada, their daily schedule would have varied by somewhere between 4.5 and 9 hours (depending on where in Canada the friend lived), in addition to any daily personal rhythm differences.

Answer (score 5):

The meanings are actually different, so which one was correct would depend on how it was intended.

'Pace' refers to the speed or tempo of something, while 'rhythm' refers to the beat or pattern, which is independent of tempo.

So if it was difficult to meet with him because you always worked days and he worked nights, rhythm would be more appropriate.
If it was difficult because he was always busy, and you were not, then it would be pace.

Comment: FWIW, I think many native speakers would be perfectly happy with *rhythm* being used to refer to tempo; phrases like "fast rhythm", "fast-paced rhythm", etc., are decently well-attested.

Answer (score 2):

I would say both are correct but I personally wouldn't say either.  I would probably say we have different schedules. I'm in the USA

Answer (score 1):

*We have different paces* is ***not*** an idiomatically established usage. Common expressions in this general area are...

> 1: *We're **out of step***
>    (We're *trying* to work together, but our efforts are just not fully co-ordinated / synchronised)
>
> 2: *You **march to the beat of a different drum***
>    (We're not compatible co-workers, because your aims are completely different to mine)

...where #1 is more likely in contexts where we *can* make minor adjustments so as to "synchronize" our actions (and quite probably *will*, since there's usually the implication that this is what we want to happen; perhaps we just weren't paying attention to the precise timing).

On the other hand, #2 is more likely in contexts where the different approaches are effectively *irreconcilable* (you have your way of doing things, I have mine, and there's nothing we can do to change that). This usage is much more "generic" (it's not just about differences in *timing*).

Answer (score -1):

Rhythm does not make sense in this context.  It could mean too many things.

Do you mean to say *you speak at different speeds*?  Then *cadence* is the word.

Do you mean to say *you sleep at different times*? Then *schedule* is the word.

*Pace* means you are literally moving at different speeds, but could be interpreted as a metaphorical difference of speed.  It is also ambiguous.

When in doubt just say what you mean using more words.

Comment: Referring to daily schedules as "rhythms" is well-attested. Referring to cadences of speech as "rhythms" is similarly acceptable.